# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n \lfloor f(n) \rfloor+(\lfloor f(n+1) \rfloor-\lfloor f(n) \rfloor)n^2}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n \lfloor f(n) \rfloor+(\lfloor f(n+1) \rfloor-\lfloor f(n) \rfloor)n^2}$$  converge for all non-constant, positive, increasing function $f$ that grows sublinearly?

The boundary cases tell us that the series obviously diverges for $f(n)=0$ and converges for $f(n)=n$ so there might be a transition between convergence and divergence (or not) depending on how slow the function $f$ grows. My intuition is that if $f$ grows extremely slow the term $n^2$ essentially makes no contribution so the series should diverge for $f$ which grows sufficiently slow.

I have tried doing limit comparison test with $b_n=\frac{1}{\lfloor f(n+1)\rfloor n^2}$ but the result is inconclusive.

I have also tried to do the integral test with numerical integration in mathematica $f(n)=log(n)$ and the integral does converge.

Any clue on how to approach this?

Comment: Have you tried any examples with specific functions $f(n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have $f \geqslant 1$ or else the denominator may vanish. In this case, if $f$ converges toward some $l \geqslant 1$, then $\lfloor f\rfloor$ is stationnary. Let $a = \lfloor f(n)\rfloor$ for $n$ large enough. Then, $\frac{1}{n\lfloor f(n)\rfloor + (\lfloor f(n + 1)\rfloor - \lfloor f(n)\rfloor)n^2} = \frac{1}{an}$ for $n$ large enough, thus the series diverges.

and even if you assume that $f(n) \rightarrow +\infty$, you may find counterexamples. Indeed, contrary to what you say, it diverges if $f(n) = \log_2(n) + 1$ (it probably also diverges for the natural logarithm but the computations are a bit more painful). Indeed, let $u_n = \frac{1}{n\lfloor f(n)\rfloor + (\lfloor f(n + 1)\rfloor - \lfloor f(n)\rfloor)n^2}$ and $M \subset \mathbb{N}$ be the set of the Mersene numbers (of the form $2^k - 1$). If $n \notin M$, then $\lfloor f(n + 1)\rfloor = \lfloor f(n)\rfloor$ thus $u_n = \frac{1}{n\lfloor f(n)\rfloor} \geqslant \frac{1}{n(\log_2(n) + 1)} \geqslant \frac{1}{n\log_2(2n)}$.

Notice that $\mathbb{N}\backslash M$ contains all the even numbers so,
$$
\sum_{n \geqslant 1} u_n \geqslant \sum_{n \geqslant 1} u_{2n} \geqslant \sum_{n \geqslant 1} \frac{1}{2n\log_2(4n)} = \frac{\ln(2)}{2}\sum_{n \geqslant 1} \frac{1}{n\ln(4n)}.
$$
And,
$$
\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x\ln(4x)} \, dx = \int_4^{+\infty} \frac{1}{y\ln(y)} \, dy = [\ln(\ln(y))]_4^{+\infty} = +\infty.
$$
By the series-integral test, $\sum_{n \geqslant 1} u_n = +\infty$.